# alpine js transition issue with browser back and stop buttons

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I'm attempting to create a page transition on new page loads with alpine js.

My idea is to have a div overlay the whole site with position fixed which I can show and hide with x-show. By default it is set to true in x-data, but on load it switches to false, with x-transition it fades out immediately. Then, on click of any "a" tag it sets to true (fading in with x transition) and then switches to off again on the new page load.

```html
<body x-data="{ loader: true }">
  <div   
    x-show="loader"
    @load.window="loader = false"
    @keyup.escape.window="loader = false"
    @click.document="if($event.target.closest('a') && !event.metaKey && !event.ctrlKey) loader = true" 
    x-transition.opacity.duration.1000ms 
    class="w-screen h-screen fixed left-0 top-0 z-50 bg-black">
      <img src="anim.gif" class="w-24 absolute right-1/2 translate-x-1/2 top-1/2 -translate-y-1/2">     
  </div>  
  <div> rest of my site ... </div>
</body>
```

The effect is a div fades in and out over the site on change of any page. I thought this was pretty clever until I realised that it doesn't work with the browser back button and stop button.

**Problem #1**
When clicking on the back button the loader div covers the page but doesn't fade out because the page doesn't reload, so it doesn't get switched to false.

**Problem #2**
When clicking the stop button after the loader has transitioned in it doesn't fade out.
`@keyup.escape.window="loader = false"` handles stopping page load with esc key quite well but I can't do the equivalent with the stop button.

I'm thinking there might be a way to say `"loader = false"` after any kind of loading is finished instead of trying to target the stop button which doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: ok so problem #1 seems to be resolved with @pageshow.window="loader = false" instead of @load.window="loader = false"

Comment: How long does it take usually to load a page? If you can estimate the maximum loading time you can enqueue a fail-safe function that flips the `loader` state after the maximum time (it can also respect `document.readyState`, so it wont interfere the loading state).

Comment: @Dauros I thought of that yesterday, works fairly well, I don't love the delay so much but it's better than getting stuck on the transition screen forever. So unless some other solution comes up I'll probably stick with that.